# Django - How to sort queryset by number of character in a field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

MyModel:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I try to sort the queryset. I just think about this:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.all().sort_by(-len(name)) #???
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you might have to sort that in python..

`sorted(MyModel.objects.all(),key=lambda o:len(o.name),reverse=True)`

or I lied ( A quick google search found the following)

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'length':'Length(name)'}).order_by('length')
```

Answer (score 36):

The new hotness (as of Django 1.8 or so) is [Length()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#length)

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
obj = MyModel.objects.all().order_by(Length('name').asc())
```

Answer (score 8):

You can of course sort the results using Python's `sorted`, but that's not ideal. Instead, you could try this:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'length':'Length(name)'}).order_by('length')
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the `extra` argument to pass an SQL function:

```
obj = MyModel.objects.all().extra(order_by=['LENGTH(`name`)'])
```

Note that this is db-specific: MySQL uses `LENGTH`, others might use `LEN`.