# The ordering name order do not satisfy my requirement

Tags: python, django

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My code is bellow:

```
class SwitchesPort(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

The ordering is `name`, you see the snapshot, this do not satisfy my need.

I want the `1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 11, 12....`, but there is `1, 10, 11, ... 2, 3, ..`.

so, if I can add a ordering item base on the name's length?

How can I create a ordering item base on the `name` field's length? so I can use

```
ordering = ['-name_length', 'name']
```

---

**EDIT-1**

I tried use`order_by(Length('name').asc())`:

```
class SwitchesPortListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SwitchesPortListSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = SwitchesPort.objects.all().order_by(Length('name').asc())
```

But however I get the bellow result, seems the `ordering name` do not work now.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: You will find all that you want with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12804856/5644965)

Comment: @Lemayzeur See my edited post, the ordering = ['-name'] do not work now.

Comment: Did you tried both Length and name? like this `queryset = SwitchesPort.objects.all().order_by(Length('name').asc(), 'name')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the multi-params as the order params, add the `name` in it:

```
class SwitchesPortListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SwitchesPortListSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = SwitchesPort.objects.extra(select={'length':'Length(name)'}).order_by('length', 'name')
```